# Debian squeeze and maven3

Tags: debian, maven-3

We're trying to configure our first "server" and we would like to have maven3 working on it. Now we've already installed a debian squeeze with a working svn so far. Now for the maven3 part I've been googling around for a tutorial on install/configure on squeeze but so far what I've found is:

```
Maven 3.x is still in beta stage [1] and Debian Squeeze 6.0 is now frozen so 
it may not be a high priority package.

If someone have enough time to package this (ie. based on maven2 package + all 
new runtime dependencies), maybe we can upload it to experimental archive.
```

So does this mean that we'll have to postpone this and go for maven2 for the time being or can we still try to get maven3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should belong to serverfault, anyway yes, you have to wait if you want an official package.

Debian is a great distribution but it doesn't offer the latest packages because their policy of great stability.

Usually if you need an higher version of a package you can add [backports sources](http://backports-master.debian.org/) to your repositories list, which provides newer versions of popular packages compiled against the stable distribution library, but currently they doesn't provide maven package, because [even in sid](http://packages.debian.org/sid/maven2) maven is at version 2.